# Why does sts ask me to choose the select type when they run the project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, configuration, sts

When sts executes the project, ask me what the select type is. I didn't ask for another project.
The sts always ask me every time they run, is there a way not to make this pop up? What did I do wrong? The class name is related to my work, so I covered it. Sorry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzi7C.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! There was a main function among the classes you asked to choose. There was something I made during the class test in the beginning, and I guess it was asking about the application.java file and what you want to run It works right away when I remove the main function of another file!